# Unable to set Activity name white colour even after changing actionbar background

Tags: android, android-styles

Im. trying to create an android app with Holo.Light.DarkActionBar theme. I made my Action bar with blue background by adding a custom style to action bar.

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">     
    <item name="android:background">@color/holo_blue_light</item>
</style>
```

But after using this, my activity name color (top left) changed to black (which was white earlier when I started my app). I'm new to android development. Please help me to reset it white. Also guide best practices for styles in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create styles.xml, use this code, edit as you wish.

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionBarText</item>
</style>

<style name="myTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbarbground</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
</style>

<style name="myTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionBarText</item>
</style>
```

in here, you will have to declare this color in color.xml file.

Comment: this question was available already, you may browse existing questions before posting new question. Welcome to stackOverFlow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

or

```
<style name="TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

In you case you should change the parent with android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Title ...